# SQL join using TOP condition in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I'm writing a stock program to improve my programming skills and I've hit a roadblock.

I have two tables I'm working with for:

```
**stocks**
---------
id
name
symbol
ipo_year
sector
industry

**stock_trends**
----------------
stock_id
trend_id
direction_id
date
price
breakout_price

**trends**
----------
id
type
```

An entry is made into the stock_trends table for that stock when a condition of one of my four trends are met.

What I'm looking to do is create a query that will return all the information from the stock table and the date from the stock_trends table where the most recent entry in stock_trends for that stock is the trend_id I'm interested in looking at.

I have this query that works great which returns the most recent trend if for a single stock.

```
SELECT top 1 stock_id, trend_id, [timestamp], price, breakout_price from stock_trends
WHERE stock_id = @stock_id and trend_id = @trend_id order by [timestamp] desc
```

I just haven't been able to figure out how to write a query that returns the stocks whose top entry in the stock_trends table is the trend I wish to analyze.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit**

So I have made some progress and I'm almost there. I'm using this query to return the max "timestamp" (it's really a date, just have to fix it) for each stock.

```
select s.*, v.latest_trend_date from stocks s
join(select stock_id, MAX(timestamp) as latest_trend_date from stock_trends st
group by st.stock_id) v on v.stock_id = s.id
```

Now if I could only find a way to determine which trend_id "latest_trend_date" is associated with I would be all set!

Comment: Which version of SQL? MSSQL/MYSQL/Oracle etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if something like this works:

```
with TrendsRanked as (
  select
    *,
    rank() over (
      partition by stock_id
      order by [date] desc
    ) as daterank_by_stock
  from stock_trends
)
  select
    s.id, s.name, s.symbol,
    TrendsRanked.[date]
  from stocks as S
  join TrendsRanked as T
  on T.stock_id = S.id
  where T.daterank_by_stock = 1
  and T.trend_id = @my_trend
```

The idea here is to add a date ranking to the stock_trends table: for a given stock, daterank_by_stock will equal 1 for the most recent stock_trends row (including ties) for that stock.

Then in the main query, the only results will be those that match the trend you're following (@my_trend) for a row in stock_trends ranked #1.

This gives what I think you want - stock information for stocks whose latest stock_trends entry happens to be an entry for the trend you're following.

Answer (score 2):

```
select stock_id
from stock_trends
where trend_id = (select top 1 trend_id
                  from stock_trends
                  order by [timestamp] desc)
```

This will select all the stock_id that are in the stock_trends table, with the same trend_id as the most recent entry in the stock_trends table.

Comment: Thanks for your response Remi. The problem with this query is that the subquery doesn't return the trend for each stock. The top entry from stock_trends may not apply to that stock. I would imagine there would have to be a join or where clause to filter for each stock.

Comment: Rémi, I think this will work if you make the subquery correlated and restrict to the trend_id of interest: ...where trend_id = (select top 1 trend_id from stock_trends as S2 where S2.stock_id = stock_trends.stock_id order by [timestamp] desc) and trend_id = @trend_id

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that [timestamp] in your original query is "date" from your table model.

```
    select s.*, st1.trend_id, st1.timestamp
    from stocks as s
    inner join (
    select top 1 stock_id, trend_id, [timestamp] as timestamp
        from stock_trends
        where stock_id = @stock_id and trend_id = @trend_id
        order by [timestamp] desc
        ) as st1
        on s.id = st1.stock_id
```

Putting the sub-query in as a joined in-line view will allow you easily to put the date into the results as you were looking to do in your specification.

> "... return all the information from the stock table and the date from the stock_trends table ..."

Comment: Thanks for your response PEBKAC. This is exactly where I got and started seeking help. The problem is with the stock_id = @stock_id in the where clause. This works perfectly if you know which stock you want analyze, but what I'm trying to do is analyze on the trend rather than the stock. I'm trying to answer the question of "Which stocks are currently in this trend and for how long".

Comment: So that we are all on the same page, can you please supply some example data and what you expect the result to be from that example?

Comment: I saw your changes. I think the addition of st1.trend_id covers what I understand you are asking for. Please advise.